# localstorage: Get specific localstorage value of which contains many items

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage, stringify

In localstorage I have key '**results**' with this **values**:

```
[{"id":"item-1","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"},
{"id":"item-2","href":"youtube.com","icon":"youtube.com"},
{"id":"item-3","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"},
{"id":"item-4","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"},
{"id":"item-5","href":"youtube.com","icon":"youtube.com"},
{"id":"item-6","href":"asos.com","icon":"asos.com"},
{"id":"item-7","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"},
{"id":"item-8","href":"mcdonalds.com","icon":"mcdonalds.com"}]
```

To get the last item I use this:

```
// this is how I parse the arrays
var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("result")); 


for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
    var item = result[i];
    $('element').val(item.href);
}
```

**How can I get the href for item-3 or for a specific ID?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has filter helper for that:

```
$(result).filter(function(){return this.id == "item-3";})[0]
```

Function for href of item with specific id would be:

```
function getItemHrefById(json, itemId){
    return json.filter(function(testItem){return testItem.id == itemId;})[0].href;
}
```

And sample usage is:

```
var href = getItemHrefById(result, "item-3");
```

You can see working example on http://jsfiddle.net/LXvLB/

**UPDATE**

If you cannot read item from local storage, maybe you forgot to call JSON.stringify when setting value:

```
localStorage["results"] = JSON.stringify([{"id":"item-1","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"}, 
{"id":"item-2","href":"youtube.com","icon":"youtube.com"}, 
{"id":"item-3","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"}, 
{"id":"item-4","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"}, 
{"id":"item-5","href":"youtube.com","icon":"youtube.com"}, 
{"id":"item-6","href":"asos.com","icon":"asos.com"}, 
{"id":"item-7","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"}, 
{"id":"item-8","href":"mcdonalds.com","icon":"mcdonalds.com"}])
```

You need to convert json to string to be properly serialized (and to use JSON.parse to get JSON back)

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/E83LD/3/) is final example.

**EDIT**

As Useless Code pointed out, this metod is substantially slower than native filter function (and custom loop but I think that introducing few new lines of code to save 20-30ms is overkill unless performance is a issue), so I'm updating my example to not use jquery filter. +1 please for his answer for that.

Also, what is important to point out here, if this array would have hundreds instead of 8 bookmarks, for loop would probably be statistically about twice faster (as it does not have to iterate through rest of the array). But, in that case it would probably be a good idea to put for loop into function which returns first found item which satisfies condition, and with [prototypejs](http://www.prototypejs.org) it probably can even be hooked up to array.

Comment: Which one I use where? It doesn't seem to be working for me... and it doesn't makes sense either. The getItemById is not a variable?

Comment: The jQuery [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method is used to filter DOM nodes, not JSON data or arrays.

Comment: @jQuerybeast sorry, my example was flawed, you need to call the function I made, not getItemById, I have fixed example, and added jsfiddle link so you can see the usage.

Comment: @Useless-code from the link you provided: "filter description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test." Set of matched elements in this case is json array. There is nothing preventing you to use it for that.

Comment: @GoranObradovic Thank you. I can set values like you did. The values are set using localstorage so when I parse them back using JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("result")); I get no results.

Comment: I have updated my answer, I believe that object in your local storage is not good, as you don't get proper json back from it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I haven't forgot to call JSOn when setting values. This is how I set them: localStorage.setItem("result", JSON.stringify(result));

Comment: Everything looks find from your code and my code because you set var result = JSON.parse(stringInStorage); and I set var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("result")); which is the same thing. The rest of the code, I copy pasted your and it doesn't work even though it works on your example

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4928/discussion-between-goran-obradovic-and-jquerybeast)

Comment: @GoranObradovic The "set of matched elements" refers to the DOM elements that were matched by a selector when the jQuery object was created. jQuery will accept non-DOM objects and this is a general enough situation that you _can_ use it to filter a generic array but it isn't really _meant_ to filter generic arrays.  Regardless, creating a jQuery instance creates a lot of unnecessary over head. This method is much slower than using a custom loop that returns as soon as it finds the item it is searching for or `Array.prototype.filter()`. Speed comparison here: http://jsfiddle.net/53v3G/

Comment: I agree. jQuery is slower method, and I did not thought about performance in this case, but 350ms of difference can be even more (second or more) if there is, lets say, 50 bookmarks. I updated my answer, +1 for you, you are right about this, although I still think that except performance (don't get me wrong, THAT IS a reason enough by itself) there is no reason not to use jQuery for this. This is a bad example, but imagine you have html text in a variable and you need to inspect it before adding to DOM, jQuery works great (lot faster to implement than regex), even if wasn't meant to do it :)

Answer (score 9):

### Using native `Array.filter`

If you are targeting only modern browsers (IE9+ or a [recent version](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) of any other major browser) you can use the JavaScript 1.6 array method [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
var testItem,
    data = [{"id":"item-1","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"},
{"id":"item-2","href":"youtube.com","icon":"youtube.com"},
{"id":"item-3","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"},
{"id":"item-4","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"},
{"id":"item-5","href":"youtube.com","icon":"youtube.com"},
{"id":"item-6","href":"asos.com","icon":"asos.com"},
{"id":"item-7","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"},
{"id":"item-8","href":"mcdonalds.com","icon":"mcdonalds.com"}];

function getItemById(data, id) {
    // filter array down to only the item that has the id
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
    var ret = data.filter(function (item) {
        return item.id === id;
    });

    // Return the first item from the filtered array   
    // returns undefined if item was not found
    return ret[0];
}


testItem = getItemById(data, 'item-3');
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/cwGeu/2/)

### Manually looping over the data

If you can't use filter you are probably stuck with just using a loop:

```
var testItem,
    data = [{"id":"item-1","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"},
{"id":"item-2","href":"youtube.com","icon":"youtube.com"},
{"id":"item-3","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"},
{"id":"item-4","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"},
{"id":"item-5","href":"youtube.com","icon":"youtube.com"},
{"id":"item-6","href":"asos.com","icon":"asos.com"},
{"id":"item-7","href":"google.com","icon":"google.com"},
{"id":"item-8","href":"mcdonalds.com","icon":"mcdonalds.com"}];

function getItemById(data, id) {
    var i, len;
    for (i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        if(id === data[i].id) {
            return data[i];
        }
    }

    return undefined;
}

testItem = getItemById(data, 'item-3');
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/gMcRB/1/)

Even though brute-forcing it with a loop might seem less elegant than using `Array.filter`, it turns out that in most cases the [loop is faster than `Array.filter`](http://jsfiddle.net/53v3G/).

### Refactoring to an object instead of an array

The best solution, assuming that the `id` of each of your items is unique, would be refactoring the way you are storing the data. Instead of an array of objects, use an object that uses the `id` as a key to store an object containing the `href` and `icon` key/property values.

```
var data = {
    "item-1": {"href": "google.com", "icon": "google.com"},
    "item-2": {"href": "youtube.com", "icon": "youtube.com"},
    "item-3": {"href": "google.com", "icon": "google.com"},
    "item-4": {"href": "google.com", "icon": "google.com"},
    "item-5": {"href": "youtube.com", "icon": "youtube.com"},
    "item-6": {"href": "asos.com", "icon": "asos.com"},
    "item-7": {"href": "google.com", "icon": "google.com"},
    "item-8": {"href": "mcdonalds.com", "icon": "mcdonalds.com"}
};
```

This would make accessing items even easier and faster:

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("result")); 
data["item-3"].href;
```

Comment: Hi and thanks. In my usage, I'm setting the testItem as JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("result")). When I do this, all the results are undefined.

Comment: I don't really know how to explain this, but I am not setting all the values like you did. I am parse'ing them and then I get undefined, in both examples.

Comment: @jQuerybeast The original example was just setting the test data and then accessing it through closure, I've altered it to use it as a parameter instead.  You could then call it passing it the data: `testItem = getItemById(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("result")), 'item-3');`.  If you are going to need to grab more than one item you should probably assign it the results of `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("result"))` to a variable instead of calling it inline though.

Comment: @Hugolpz you tend to change answers too much. You change code, you change meaning. I for one will never approve those edits. Won't fight you over this one, but my personal advice is don't do such changes. Feel free to fix grammar and spelling but let the post author fix code or change variable names or whatever. Don't do it yourself.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: web 2.0. If it's a clarification, better clarification, better hierarchy-segmentation, better readability : let's just do it.

Comment: @Hugolpz I said my part. Many of your suggestions are being rejected and you'll soon be banned from suggesting further edits if you're not already. This is Q&A site, not Wikipedia.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: ??? you are telling a new user he may already be banned for good faith edits you just expressed as not welcome few hours ago. The properties of "new user" entering a community is we don't precisely know the local rules, nor tools. Learning is ongoing *after* feedbacks. There is a button "edit", there is a side panel saying clarification is welcome. You are the first negative feedback I get.

Comment: @Hugolpz [one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1484730). [Two](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1482254). [Three](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1476585). The fact some users agree with you does not make it proper as you see many users reject your edits, not just me.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: oh... I was not aware of these feedbacks / practices.

Comment: @Hugolpz I've been a bit annoyed with these edits too. Adding the header to each of the different techniques is okay, but separating the redundant parts of the example code makes it less clear and harder to follow. Likewise combining the Update and Better Solution headers into "Update/Best solution" changes the meaning. The "update" was that loops are faster than filters. The "Better" solution I added requires refactoring but is even faster then loops, combining them under one header muddies that distinction.

Comment: @UselessCode: I was not aware that Stackoverflow is more concervative for edit policy than wikipedia and pushed boldly, which took me time. I will simply be more cautious from now on and edit less.

Comment: Ok, so I now understand better SOF's local edit practices. Should we delete these out-of-the-topic comments ?

Answer (score 0):

for the jquery filter method, I think using a callback function, and bind the search parameter is more elegant and readable:

```
function filterById(id, i, obj) {
    return obj.id === id;
}

function getItemHrefById(json, itemId) {
    return $(json).filter(filterById.bind(null, itemId))[0].href;
}
```

[da usual fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5b7gB/)

(however, i prefer the "for loop" approach" for this!!)