# Return last element in localStorage array

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble getting the any precise value or name form my array in localStorage.

This is my localStorage:
[image: JSON Result]

What I want to do is retrieve the last item and set a variable to the value of the first item in the last entry (ReportReference). The reason being to check if there is already an item in there with the same value for `ReportReference` so not to save another copy of the form that I am saving and only update the fields again to save back into localStorage.

The method below is a save for later button which just saves the vales to an array.

```
// Add to local Storage
$('.SaveStore').on('click', addStorage);

function addStorage(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var keyIndex = localStore.getValue(REPORTS_KEY);

    console.log(keyIndex);
    for (var i = 0; i < keyIndex.length; i++) {
        //console.log(keyIndex[i]);
        for (var key in keyIndex[i]) {
            //console.log(keyIndex[i][key]);
            var test = keyIndex[i][key];
            console.log(test.value);
        }
    }

    var form = $('form').serializeArray();
    //console.log(form);
    var reports = localStore.getValue(REPORTS_KEY);
    if (reports == null) {
        reports = [];
    }
    reports.push(form);
    localStore.setValue(REPORTS_KEY, reports);
    clearFormElements();
}
```

the `console.log(test.value)` will give me all the results, but what ever I try It doesn't seem to give me any results.

```
Console.log(test[0].value);  // Returns value undefined
```

[image: Result from console]

I have looked at this post and tried to do what they say but haven't had any luck: [localstorage: Get specific localstorage value of which contains many items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101113/localstorage-get-specific-localstorage-value-of-which-contains-many-items)

As I can't retrieve the Item I want to pass to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
for (var i = 0, formLen = keyIndex.length; i < formLen; i++) {
    var serializedForm = keyIndex[i];
    for (var j = 0, fieldsLen = serializedForm.length; j < fieldsLen; j++) {
            var field = serializedForm[j];

            if (field.name == "ReportReference" && field.value == "bbb") {
                    console.log(keyIndex[i][j]);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it has helped me get any values that already exist in my arrays which I can then do something with.