# How to get unique id from localStorage for delete button

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, local-storage

I have been trying for getting an id from localStorage but unable to achieve it.
My localStorage inside `events` contains such as below.

`[{"id":"ef5","title":"wan","start":"2016-05-12","end":"2016-05-13"},{"id":"ef6","title":"wana","start":"2016-05-21","end":"2016-05-22"},{"id":"ef7","title":"haha","start":"2016-05-25","end":"2016-05-26"},{"id":"ef8","title":"asdas","start":"2016-05-20","end":"2016-05-21"},{"id":"ef9","title":"sdas","start":"2016-05-19","end":"2016-05-20"}]`

Now i will provide 2 coding with different method that i have tried so far. For information, i look through into this topic: [localstorage: Get specific localstorage value of which contains many items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101113/localstorage-get-specific-localstorage-value-of-which-contains-many-items)
but none works for me.

I did tried coding as below:

1st method:

```
$("#deleteEventYes").click(function(){
var indexDel = localStorage.getItem("events");
var deleteId = calEvent.id;
var result = localStorage.getItem("events"); 


    function getItemHrefById(json, itemId){ 
    return $(json).filter(function(){return this.id == itemId;})[0].href; 
    } 

    var href = getItemHrefById(result, deleteId);   

    alert(href);   });
```

Above code show some kind of array method (i think) where i'm using indexDel to get item from localStorage (`events`) while deleteId i took from calEvent.id which is the id for the event that has been clicked for to be deleted. Other than that, i think you guys know what it is. However for this method, i use `result` variable instead of indexDel. Thus don't mind if i getItem from localStorage 2 times

2nd method:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < indexDel.length ; i += 1) {
    if(deleteId == indexDel[i].id) {
    return indexDel[i];
    console.log(deleteId);
    console.log(indexDel[i]);
    }
}
return null;
```

Above code is using custom loop i think. The declaration of variable for indexDel is still the same with first method. I try to use the refactoring method but it seems its hard for me to understand how is it to be done. Is it because my variable placement is wrong? or is it because it is not suitable for my case?

NOTE: I want to delete an event inside eventClick function, and so far i did retrieve the id and remove the event from the calendar based on id. However my only problem now is to match the deleted event id with the id inside my localStorage and remove the item. So far getting an id from the is quite complicated for me.

**UPDATED**

I already done something like this but still don't work. Anyone can tell me what went wrong here? It is not giving me any error but it just do nothing. Not even delete.
https://jsfiddle.net/v35a2o07/3/

Comment: `localStorage` stores values as strings.  Be sure to `JSON.parse()` your values prior to operating on them.  :)

Comment: did you mean like these? https://jsfiddle.net/v35a2o07/
It is not working :(
I think i might misunderstand with variable placement. That is why it's hard for me to follow such method

Comment: Use `delete` keyword to delete array elements.

Comment: @AhKing The fiddle is incomplete. jQuery is not defined, the handler is not closed (i.e. `});`), element `#deleteEventYes` does not exist...

Comment: @War10ck It is just a coding for my delete part.. Besides, my full coding is a mess right now :P. So it might be better if i am not give full one for a moment. Sorry for that. I have solve it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I think i figure it out :)
It is because i forgot to `setItem` & `stringify` it after using `splice`.
Here i can assume splice is the same as add/remove such wrote at w3school 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

"The splice() method adds/removes items to/from an array, and returns the removed item(s)."

My final code is on this fiddle given: https://jsfiddle.net/v35a2o07/4/

So the concept is:

1) First step is declare one variable that parse your localStorage key such as`var items = JSON.parse(localStorage["events"]);` so that you can use it for the loop

2) Use for loop to determine the length of localStorage based on localStorage key that we parse on No. 1

3) Use if statement to check the comparison between localStorage data with our desire data such as `if(items[i].id == deleteId){`

4) This is OPTIONAL but important. To enable you to check the comparison is right, create one alert or console.log() and stringify it because if you don't, you will only see [object,object]. The coding such as `alert(JSON.stringify(items[i])+"<<<>>>"+deleteId);` Make some `else statement` too if you want to be sure.

5) When all the conditions are correct, then you are ready to do some action to it. For my case, i just use `splice()` to delete it. It is also can be used to add item. I am not sure how is it done but try to search for it to get more info.

6) After splicing it, it is safely to break and get out from the loop.

7) This is important otherwise, it will not work. Don't forget to set it back to localStorage and stringify it such as `localStorage.setItem('events', JSON.stringify(items));`

That's it.
I wish this would help anyone that needs it. If i have make wrong statement or  wrong concept, please make correction and clarify it for anyone.

Cheers.